# Как заставить скрипт подсчитывать все заполненные поля?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, который в реальном времени подсчитывает все заполненные поля в блоке.
Но код не хочет работать с полями, которые появляются динамически.
Изначально выведено 2 поля, при нажатии на второе поле автоматом появляется 3 поле, при вводе в 3 поле появляется 4 и так далее. Появившиеся поля уже кодом не учитываются, скрипт не хочет их считать. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста!
Вот пример:

```js
// Подсчет заполненых input ингредиенты 
$(function() {
  $('input[id*="ingred"]').on('input', function() {
    var countNonEmptyIngrInput = $('input[id*="ingred"]').filter(function() {
      return this.value.trim() != '';
    }).length;
    $('input#xf_kol').val(countNonEmptyIngrInput);
  });
});


//Поля ингредиентов
function addIngredient(group, name, value, unit) {
  name = name || '';
  value = value || '';
  unit = unit || '';
  var id = ++ingredientsCount;
  var groupId = group.data('id');
  var rowCount = group.find('tr').length;
  var inputHTML = '<tr class="ingredient_box"><td>' + (rowCount < 1 ? 'Название ингредиента <span style="color:red;">*' : '') + '</td><td><div class="form-box-cont">' +
    '<div class="form-box-ingrid"><input type="text" placeholder="Название ингредиента" id="ingred' + id + '" name="ingred_group[' + groupId + '][ingredient][' + id + '][name]" value="' + name + '"></div>' +
    '<div class="form-box-inp"><input type="text" placeholder="Кол-во" name="ingred_group[' + groupId + '][ingredient][' + id + '][value]" value="' + value + '">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Ед.Изм." id="unit' + id + '" name="ingred_group[' + groupId + '][ingredient][' + id + '][unit]" value="' + unit + '">' +
    '</div></div></td>' +
    (rowCount >= 2 ? '<td class="td-comment"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="inp-close" title="Удалить список">x</a>' :
      '<th class="td-comment td-comment-pad">') +
    '</tr>';
  group.find('.ingredient-cont').append(inputHTML);

}

function delIngredient() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  return false;
}

function addGroup(name) {
  name = name || '';
  groupsCount++;
  var id = groupsCount;
  var html = '<div class="group-wrap" data-id="{id}"><div class="border-header"><span>{title}</span></div> \
        <div class="form-table ingredient-cont"><div class="ingredient-cont_item"><div class="title-Group">Для чего ингредиенты <span class="td-comment">Например: <a href="javascript:void(0)">Для соуса</a></span></div><input type="text" name="ingred_group[{id}][name]" value="{name}"> \
        </div></div></div>';
  if (groupsCount == 1) {
    html = html.replace(/\{title\}/, 'Добавить ингредиент');
  } else {
    html = html.replace(/\{title\}/, 'Дополнительный список <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-block" title="Удалить список">x</a>');
  }
  html = html.replace(/\{id\}/g, id);
  html = html.replace(/\{name\}/g, name);
  return $(html).appendTo('.add-list-box');
}

function delGroup() {
  $(this).parents('.group-wrap').remove();
  return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-list').click(function() {
    var group = addGroup();
    addIngredient(group);
    addIngredient(group);
    return false;
  });

  $('div.ingredients')
    .on('click change', '.ingredient-cont .form-box-ingrid input', function() {
      $(this).parents('.ingredient-cont').removeClass('has-error');
      if ($(this).parents('tr').is(':last-child')) {
        addIngredient($(this).parents('.group-wrap'));
      }
      return false;
    })
    .on('click', '.inp-close', delIngredient)
    .on('click', '.close-block', delGroup);

});


var ingredientsCount = 0;
var groupsCount = 0;

if (typeof ingredientsList !== 'undefined' && ingredientsList.length) {
  groupsCount = ingredientsList.length;

  $.map(ingredientsList, function(data) {
    var group = addGroup(data['name']);

    $.map(data['ingredient'], function(ingredient) {
      addIngredient(group, ingredient['name'], ingredient['value'], ingredient['unit']);
    });

    addIngredient(group);
  });
} else {
  // ингредиенты
  if (!groupsCount) {
    var group = addGroup();
    addIngredient(group);
    addIngredient(group);
  }
}
```

```css
/* - Блок добавить ингредиенты- */
.ingredient_box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-box.ingredients {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form-box.ingredients::after {
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleX(1.082);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:780px) {
  .form-box.ingredients::after {
    transform: scaleX(1.2);
  }
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-box-cont {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0 10px;
}

.ingredient_box td:nth-child(2),
.form-box-ingrid {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.form-box-ingrid input {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-box-inp input {
  max-width: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .ingredient-cont_item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 0 20px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-table input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.ingredient-cont_item .title-Group {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-box-inp input {
    width: 42%;
  }
}

.title-Group {
  padding-right: 30px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list-box .form-table .td-comment {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #878787;
}

.form-box.ingredients .border-header {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #c5c5c5;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .border-header span {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: -13px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #2a82c5;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 23px;
  line-height: 21px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px 2px 26px;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px #dadada;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px #dadada;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #dadada;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '+';
  top: 5px;
  left: 6px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #2a82c5;
}

.form-box.ingredients .add-list:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d81760;
}

.form-box.ingredients .close-block {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: red;
}

.form-box.ingredients .inp-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: -12px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-box ingredients">
  <div class="add-list-box"></div>
  <div class="border-header">
    <span><a href="" class="add-list">Добавить еще список</a></span>
  </div>
</div>

СКОЛЬКО ЗАПОЛНЕНО
<input type="text" name="kol" id="xf_kol" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй вот так:

```js
$('body').on('input', 'input[id*="ingred"]', ({currentTarget})=>{
    const value = $(currentTarget).val();
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо  за подсказку! Мой пример был тоже верным, нужно было обратиться к всему документу а не конкретно к блоку. Оставил свой вариант, прописав BODY. Вам спасибо еще раз!